# How do I escape underscores in data explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

It seems that underscore (_) is a wildcard character in Data Explorer.  How do I escape it to search for an actual underscore?

Better - is there any indexing on words a la Lucene or RegEx support that I can access in the Data Explorer or do I have to do brute-force LIKE queries?

Even better - is there any way to do a search based on text, not markdown code?

For example, if I want to find all posts with the word "bat" in them (not the words "batch" or "rebate") but don't care if there's some formatting around "bat", do I have to write:

```
select [Post Link] from Posts 
where body like '% bat %'
or body like '% *bat* %'
or body like '% *bat* %' 
or body like '% bat* %' ... etc.
```

Comment: If you could comment on my answer as to whether any of its suggestions worked, that could help future people with the same question.

Comment: @msh210 I agree. I haven't gotten a chance to try anything.  If your suggestion works, I will accept.  Otherwise, I will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* the Data Explorer uses T-SQL. *If* that's right, then the following — based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/863534 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/194652 — should work:

> It seems that underscore (_) is a wildcard character in Data Explorer.  How do I escape it to search for an actual underscore?

Use `[_]`.

> Even better - is there any way to do a search based on text, not markdown code?

Not that I know of.

> For example, if I want to find all posts with the word "bat" in them (not the words "batch" or "rebate") but don't care if there's some formatting around "bat", do I have to write:
>
> ```
> select [Post Link] from Posts 
> where body like '% bat %'
> or body like '% *bat* %'
> or body like '% *bat* %' 
> or body like '% bat* %' ... etc.
> ```

This should work: `body like '%[^a-z]bat[^a-z]%'` (if search is case insensitive, anyway. I don't know whether it is). Or `body like '%[ _*'"]bat[ _*.,;:!?'"]%'`, say.

Comment: This looks good.  Thanks!  (example: http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/query/115197/uses-of-any-given-word-by-user)